# Understanding the Cowboy's threat in Mulholland Drive

Tags: plot-explanation, david-lynch, mulholland-drive

In mulholland Drive, when the Cowboy asks Adam to cast Camilla Rhodes for the lead role in his movie, He says that **Adam will see him one more time if he does good, or two more times if he does bad.**

Given the context and tone, It's obviously a threat. However, it's a rather vague one.

I've considered that, as the cowboy might be religious, he expects to meet Adam in the next life, either way. But if Adam doesn't follow his demand, he plans to kill him, and thus see him one additional time before that.

**But that seems a bit simplistic (for a David Lynch film).**

Thinking further, I noticed that Adam does as asked, yet he *never* actually sees the Cowboy again during the film. The viewer, however, sees him **two more times**:

1. When he wakes Diane up
2. During the party at Adam's house

Is that intended to put the viewer in Adam's place? Maybe it means that the viewer somehow "did bad"?

**But that seems too much reading into it.**

I've found little to no discussion about it anywhere. Any thoughts?

Comment: My take on Mulholland Drive is that it might be a commentary by Lynch on Hollywood.  The Cowboy seems to be some kind of demon (aka a studio exec) and the rotting corpses in the apartment might be Lynch's view of the commercial film industry...

Comment: (Brilliant film, btw.  Made me even angrier about the Cremaster Cycle b/c Lynch is a director who can actually pull that kind of thing off, make it impeccably beautiful and also grotesque, and do it in 2.5 hours;)

Comment: This (over?) explains the most common interpretation of the film, including the Cowboy: https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2012/03/04/film-crit-hulk-smash-hulk-vs-the-genius-of-mulholland-drive